# Double Pop Up in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still kind of new on coding, and I'm helping some friends with some stuff.

So, I made a pop-up text inside my code, this with a button, I want to make a 2nd and up to a 4th one, each with it's own text and specific stuff, but I haven't been able to, any help please?

Here's my code.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#FFE4C4;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br><br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn1" class="button"><H1>FRUTAS Y VERDURAS</H1></button>

        <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <ol style="list-style-type: 1">
              <li>Deben lavarse con agua y utilizar media cucharada de cloro.</li>
              <li>Lavar las frutas y verduras y si es necesario dejarlas en agua con el cloro y escurrirlas después de 30 minutos.</li>
              <li>Secarlas bien.</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `"So, I made a pop-up text inside my code, this with a button, I want to make a 2nd and up to a 4th one, each with it's own text and specific stuff"`  umm what?

Comment: Why not use the same code to create the other buttons and modals? Or have you copied the code from someone else and do not understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below snippet. Give all modal a unique `ID` and put the same value in  `target` of the button.

```js
var modal;


btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click',btnClick,false);
}

spans = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener('click',spanClick,false);
}

function btnClick() {
    modal = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("target"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function spanClick() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <br><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1" class="button" target="myModal1"><H1>FRUTAS Y VERDURAS</H1></button>
<button id="myBtn1" class="button" target="myModal2"><H1>FRUTAS Y VERDURAS</H1></button>
<button id="myBtn1" class="button" target="myModal3"><H1>FRUTAS Y VERDURAS</H1></button>
<button id="myBtn1" class="button" target="myModal4"><H1>FRUTAS Y VERDURAS</H1></button>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    1
    <ol style="list-style-type: 1">
        <li>Deben lavarse con agua y utilizar media cucharada de cloro.</li>
        <li>Lavar las frutas y verduras y si es necesario dejarlas en agua con el cloro y escurrirlas después de 30 minutos.</li>
        <li>Secarlas bien.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    2
    <ol style="list-style-type: 1">
        <li>Deben lavarse con agua y utilizar media cucharada de cloro.</li>
        <li>Lavar las frutas y verduras y si es necesario dejarlas en agua con el cloro y escurrirlas después de 30 minutos.</li>
        <li>Secarlas bien.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    3
    <ol style="list-style-type: 1">
        <li>Deben lavarse con agua y utilizar media cucharada de cloro.</li>
        <li>Lavar las frutas y verduras y si es necesario dejarlas en agua con el cloro y escurrirlas después de 30 minutos.</li>
        <li>Secarlas bien.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal4" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    4
    <ol style="list-style-type: 1">
        <li>Deben lavarse con agua y utilizar media cucharada de cloro.</li>
        <li>Lavar las frutas y verduras y si es necesario dejarlas en agua con el cloro y escurrirlas después de 30 minutos.</li>
        <li>Secarlas bien.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: happy coding :-)